# Ordering MySQL data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display my users' pictures, grouped by date, like in my attached picture. What do I need to do?

I have so far:

```
$connect= //connection info;
$query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= $user_id AND picture= IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC";

$result= ($connect, $query); 

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
};
```

And my table structure:

```
| user_id | post_date | story | image |
|-------------------------------------|
| 14      | mar 2012  | BLOB  | a.jpg |
| 14      | apr 2012  | BLOB  | b.jpg |
| 14      | feb 2012  | BLOB  | c.jpg |
| 14      | mar 2012  | BLOB  | d.jpg |
|_____________________________________|
```

But this code only displays ALL of a users' collected images. How do I group them?

[image: Photos]

Comment: Can we see your full query, and all associated fields from the table you're calling from? This will help refine the SQL.

Comment: What time information and format your DB entries have ?

Comment: A multidimensional array.  $userPictures['date'] = data;  Then render each array as a group.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of the query (adjust for your particular query):

```
ORDER BY date ASC
```

For better details, show us your query and the table description or a sample table row.

Answer (score 0):

Add ORDER BY date DESC (seems you already have) to the end of your query as dotancohan suggested and use your for loop with time checking, for example

```
$date = "0";

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  if (date('dmY', $date) != date('dmY', $row['date'])) {
     echo "<p> NEW ROW, DATE: $row[date]</p>";
     $date = $row['date'];
  }

  echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
}
```

The code assumes your date in mysql is in epoch format (integers of seconds starting from jan 1 1970). Seems you put only month and year as strings, then just use **$date != $row['date']** in if statement without translating it by date function.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, extract the month and year from your date like this:

```
SELECT *, MONTH(date_field) AS month, YEAR(date_field) AS year FROM table 
ORDER BY date_field DESC
```

Then in your php view do something like this:

```
<div class="month-wrap">
    <? $i = 0; foreach ($data as $item){ ?>

        <? if ($i > 0 && $last_month != $item['month'] && $last_year != $item['year']){ ?>
            </div><div class="month-wrap">
            <?= $item['month'] ?>, <?= $item['year'] ?>
        <? } ?>

        <? if ($i == 0){ ?>
            <?= $item['month'] ?>, <?= $item['year'] ?>
        <? } ?>

        <img src="<?= $item['image'] ?>" />

        <?
            $last_month = $item['month'];
            $last_year = $item['year'];
        ?>

    <? $i++; } ?>
</div>
```